Control depth in the right sidebar toc when using the Furo theme
I would like to control the size of the right sidebar in Furo theme for sphinx documentation, for example set it to 1. However, I only found ways to control the depth of the left sidebar. Does anyone has an idea to control the right contents sidebar depth ?

I read on the doc here that we can hide content with :hide-toc: but it is not really a solution...
